# ASP.Net MVC "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

View

```
@using LearningMVCBLL;
@model LearningMVC.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CityDetails";
}

<h2>CityDetails</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>City Name</td>
            <td>@foreach (CityMaster city in @Model.GetCityDetails())
                {
                @city.City_Name
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        @* <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>*@
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LearningMVC.Models;
using LearningMVCBLL;

namespace LearningMVC.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Index/

        public ActionResult CityDetails()
        {
            User User = new User();
            List<CityMaster> city = new List<CityMaster>();
            city = User.GetCityDetails();
            return View(city);
        }

    }
}
```

Model

```
using LearningMVCBLL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LearningMVC.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        LearningMVCDataContext _dbContext = new LearningMVCDataContext();
        public List<CityMaster> GetCityDetails()
        {
            List<CityMaster> city = _dbContext.CityMasters.Where(c => c.City_ID == 2).ToList();
            return city;
        }
    }

}
```

I am new to MVC please help me in resolving this problem. Error that I am getting is "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LearningMVCBLL.CityMaster]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LearningMVC.Models.User'."

I am using LINQ to fetch the data from the database. Please explain me what I am doing wrong or I am completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action method you have this code...

```
public ActionResult CityDetails() 
{ 
    User User = new User(); 
     List<CityMaster> city = new List<CityMaster>(); 
     city = User.GetCityDetails(); 
     return View (city);
 }
```

You need to change it to this....

```
public ActionResult CityDetails() 
{
     User user = new User();
      return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Leo answer, if you want have User in view. Or you may change view:
Replace model

```
@model LearningMVC.Models.User
```

To

```
@model List<CityMaster>
```

And in `foreach` replace

```
@foreach (CityMaster city in @Model.GetCityDetails())
```

To

```
@foreach (CityMaster city in Model)
```

Comment: @ManojSethi, I'm glad to help. By the way, if you want and use this answer, why you marked different answer as the best?

Comment: I actually want User to be returned in the view, but for now both answers worked for me so I marked Leo's answer as it gives me what I want to achieve. I hope StackOverflow allows multiple answers to mark correct.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have an answer you'd be better of constructing the data you need in the controller.

Example:

```
public class CityDetailsModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cities> { get; set; }
}


public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Index/
    public ActionResult CityDetails()
    {
        CityDetailsModel model = new CityDetailsModel();
        model.User = new User();
        model.Cities = GetCityDetails();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using LearningMVCBLL;
@model LearningMVC.Models.CityDetailsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CityDetails";
}
<h2>CityDetails</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>City Name</td>
            <td>
            @foreach (CityMaster city in @Model.Cities)
            {
                @city.City_Name
            }
            </td>
        </tr>
        @* <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>*@
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Sivermind I think your answer is helps me to create more strongly typed view. Am I right? @silvermind

Comment: @ManojSethi Yes indeed ;) It helps you to prevent clutter in your views using methods. An extra advantage is debugging. Debugging from your view into methods is not really working that awesome. No you have the advantage that when you get an exception regarding logic, it happens in the controller.

Comment: Thanks very much I am new to MVC pattern. Thanks for explaining it in detail.